# Solr CDCR doesn't work if the authentication is enabled

Tags: authentication, solr, solrcloud

I set up CDCR in my test environment and it worked perfectly until I uploaded 
security.json files to Zookeeper clusters of a Target and a Source 
SolrClouds. security.json files are identical for both Clouds as well as 
collections name. 
The Source has the next errors:

```
Request to collection col01 failed due to (401) 

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$RouteException: Error from server at http://targethost:port/solr/col01_shard1_replica1: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized request, Response code: 401</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/col01_shard1_replica1/update. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized request, Response code: 401</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.directUpdate(CloudSolrClient.java:819)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.sendRequest(CloudSolrClient.java:1263)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(CloudSolrClient.java:1134)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.request(CloudSolrClient.java:1073)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:160)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:177)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.CdcrReplicator.sendRequest(CdcrReplicator.java:136)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.CdcrReplicator.run(CdcrReplicator.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.CdcrReplicatorScheduler.lambda$null$0(CdcrReplicatorScheduler.java:81)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://targethost:port/solr/col01_shard1_replica1: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized request, Response code: 401</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/col01_shard1_replica1/update. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized request, Response code: 401</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:578)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:279)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrClient.doRequest(LBHttpSolrClient.java:447)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrClient.request(LBHttpSolrClient.java:388)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.lambda$directUpdate$0(CloudSolrClient.java:796)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 4 more
```

Any idea how should I fix it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, it appears that the target SolrCloud is trying to authenticate incoming requests from the source using `PKIAuthenticationPlugin`, but since neither of the source nodes are registered on the target by default, the latter gives the following error:

> ERROR (qtp1265210847-32) [   ] o.a.s.s.PKIAuthenticationPlugin Decryption failed , key must be wrong

After some investigation of the `PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java`, I found out that the following piece of code would reject the authentication request:

```
Public Key getRemotePublicKey(String nodename) {
  if(!cores.getZkController().getZkStateReader().getClusterState(). getLiveNodes().contains(nodename)) 
return null;
}
```

So, to overcome this, I simply added the node names (located in `/live_nodes` section) of the source to the target Zookeeper, and the replication started working with `security.json` enforced on both sides.

Comment: thanks. With added name of node to `/live_nodes`, CDCR works.

Comment: I know this is old, but I have a legacy cloud (ver 5.5.4) app with this problem. Can you be more specific about what you added? My node names exist in /live_nodes, but nowhere in the clusterState.json. Did you add them somewhere in there?